# Centering a matrix in a figure?

Tags: floats, matrices

I have a matrix that I would like to be centered in the middle of the page, however it is showing up left-aligned.

```
\begin{figure}[ht]$
\centering
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0       & C_l       & 0         & 0         & \dots     & \dots     & \dots     & 0         \\
        0       & 0         & C_l       & 0         & \dots     & \dots     & \dots     & \vdots    \\
        0       & C_r       & 0         & C_l       & \dots     & \dots     & \dots     & \vdots    \\
        0       & 0         & C_r       & 0         & \ddots    & \dots     & \dots     & \vdots    \\
        \vdots  & \hdots    & \hdots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & \hdots    & \vdots    \\
        \vdots  & \hdots    & \hdots    & \hdots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & C_l       & 0         \\
        \vdots  & \hdots    & \hdots    & \hdots    & \hdots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & 0         \\
        0       & \hdots    & \hdots    & \hdots    & \hdots    & \hdots    & C_r       & 0         \\
    \end{bmatrix}$
\caption{$n \times n$ transition matrix for a classical random walk.}
\end{figure}
```

How can I center this matrix?

Comment: Omit the `figure` environment and use \usepackage{caption} if you need to make legend for that matrix. Change to `captionof` also. Please post a MWE also.

Comment: `\begin{figure}[ht]\centering
$\begin{bmatrix}`...

Comment: @ferahfeza That's what I already have.

Comment: @ChristianH. The caption disappears if I remove the figure.

Comment: @sonicboom, yes I forgot the state the usage of`captionof` in my 1st comment, sorry. See my (possible) solution.

Comment: `figure` is a floating environment, i.e. they are placed to positions where `LaTeX` etc. thinks they should go.

Comment: @sonicboom No, that's not what you have. Place the `\centering` before `$`. Edit: I see jfbu mentioned this in his answer.

Comment: @sonicboom: If you want your matrix to float (around) please also have a look on Ethan's or jfbu's solutions...

Comment: Also please always post complete documents (as in the answers) not just a fragment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK, will do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just move the `\centering` out of the math material enclosed in `$...$`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    $\begin{bmatrix}
        0       & C_l       & 0         & 0         & \dots     & \dots     & \dots     & 0         \\
        0       & 0         & C_l       & 0         & \dots     & \dots     & \dots     & \vdots    \\
        0       & C_r       & 0         & C_l       & \dots     & \dots     & \dots     & \vdots    \\
        0       & 0         & C_r       & 0         & \ddots    & \dots     & \dots     & \vdots    \\
        \vdots  & \hdots    & \hdots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & \hdots    & \vdots    \\
        \vdots  & \hdots    & \hdots    & \hdots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & C_l       & 0         \\
        \vdots  & \hdots    & \hdots    & \hdots    & \hdots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & 0         \\
        0       & \hdots    & \hdots    & \hdots    & \hdots    & \hdots    & C_r       & 0         \\
    \end{bmatrix}$
\caption{$n \times n$ transition matrix for a classical random walk.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, it is working...{embarrassed!}

Answer (score 4):

If you want a figure (floating), replace `$\begin{bmatrix} ... $` with `\begin{equation*}\begin{bmatrix} ... \end{equation*}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0       & C_l       & 0         & 0         & \dots     & \dots     & \dots     & 0         \\
        0       & 0         & C_l       & 0         & \dots     & \dots     & \dots     & \vdots    \\
        0       & C_r       & 0         & C_l       & \dots     & \dots     & \dots     & \vdots    \\
        0       & 0         & C_r       & 0         & \ddots    & \dots     & \dots     & \vdots    \\
        \vdots  & \hdots    & \hdots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & \hdots    & \vdots    \\
        \vdots  & \hdots    & \hdots    & \hdots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & C_l       & 0         \\
        \vdots  & \hdots    & \hdots    & \hdots    & \hdots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & 0         \\
        0       & \hdots    & \hdots    & \hdots    & \hdots    & \hdots    & C_r       & 0         \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\caption{$n \times n$ transition matrix for a classical random walk.}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is suited for 'fixed' positioning of content with a caption, i.e. the content should not float around.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My very sophisticated matrix}
\begingroup
\centering%
\(%
    \begin{bmatrix}%
        0       & C_l       & 0         & 0         & \dots     & \dots     & \dots     & 0         \\
        0       & 0         & C_l       & 0         & \dots     & \dots     & \dots     & \vdots    \\
        0       & C_r       & 0         & C_l       & \dots     & \dots     & \dots     & \vdots    \\
        0       & 0         & C_r       & 0         & \ddots    & \dots     & \dots     & \vdots    \\
        \vdots  & \hdots    & \hdots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & \hdots    & \vdots    \\
        \vdots  & \hdots    & \hdots    & \hdots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & C_l       & 0         \\
        \vdots  & \hdots    & \hdots    & \hdots    & \hdots    & \ddots    & \ddots    & 0         \\
        0       & \hdots    & \hdots    & \hdots    & \hdots    & \hdots    & C_r       & 0         \\
    \end{bmatrix}%
\)%
\captionof{figure}{$n \times n$ transition matrix for a classical random walk.}%
\endgroup%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like this....

Comment: You may want to localise the effect of `\centering` with a group, or just use a displayed math environment instead.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, you are right, but I want to keep my 'solution' similar to the post.

Comment: Why is it still showing up left aligned on mine...and it's also complaining about missing math symbols when I use your code. Edit: Sorry, it is working...{embarrassed!}